# Look at your watch and tell me what time is it. vs Look at your watch and tell me what time it is

Tags: word-order

1. Look at your watch and tell me what time is it.
2. Look at your watch and tell me what time it is.

Is the second variant correct?

Answer (score 10):

Strictly speaking, only #2 is "correct".

You ask someone to tell you *something = a **noun phrase***, as in *the time [that] **it is** [now] is 10 o'clock.* That's the standard / default English sequence *subject + verb + object*.

In English, we normally ***invert*** the *subject + verb* element when asking questions, as in *What time **is it**?* (but not in the statement / answer ***It's*** = **It is** 10 o'clock).

OP's example #1 is increasingly common among younger native speakers, so I wouldn't want to say it's "wrong". But historically it's long been associated with non-native speakers. So on the one hand you might want to use format #1 yourself - to appear more "with it", and in tune with those younger speakers. On the other hand, older or more pedantic people will tend to think you just don't know "proper" English. My advice is to stick with format #2 in your own constructions, but maybe it depends a bit on who you're talking to.

Comment: If subject+verb are inverted shouldn't that be "what time is it?".

Comment: "What time is it?" is a *question*, so ***is it*** is "inverted" from standard ***it is***. As in Question: *How old **is he**?*, Answer: ***He is** 10*. More definitively, in constructions involving ***tell*** as well as a ***wh-*** question word, *Tell me who **you are*** is "correct" (it's an imperative command, equivalent to the *actual* Question form *Who **are you**?*). And *Tell me who **are you*** is "badly-formed", but not uncommon today. The rule isn't all that complicated, and it would be better for you to apply it consistently even if not all native speakers always do.

Comment: Unless you massage the punctuation to make number one a question: *Look at your watch and tell me: What time is it?*

Comment: @Davo: I think that's a bit of "use / mention" confusion. Syntactically, that should be articulated as *[**You**, imperative subject] Look at your watch and tell me **the answer to the question** "What time is it?"* And strictly speaking it's "cheating" to discard the highlighted element their.

Comment: So "What time is it?" is correct as this is question, and "tell me what time it is" is correct as it's not a question but an imperative command. Have i got things right?

Comment: @eefar: Well done, yes. You have it exactly right!

Comment: @eefar: But note that it's not *specifically* "imperative". It's a matter of *whether it's a straightforward **wh- question** or not*. Thus *I wonder what time **it is*** isn't an imperative - nor is it actually a *question*, which is why it doesn't end with a question mark. And at least *some* people will think you're being "sloppy" if you say *I wonder what time **is it***. Note that English questions always have ***rising intonation***, and if you included that in my last example it wouldn't sound so bad (it's the spoken equivalent of punctuating Davo's example with quote / question marks).

Comment: "younger, poorly-educated native speakers".  FTFY.

Comment: @RonJohn: I wouldn't want to make too much of that "poorly educated" point. I'm approaching pension age, and have a degree in language & linguistics, but I certainly use the "inverted" form myself sometimes in contexts that aren't explicitly framed as questions. But your comment is more than welcome - I'm not personally bothered by the possibility that someone might think I'm dumber or less well educated than they are because of the way I speak. If anything, I tend to take it as the *opposite* - a sign of rigid inflexible thinking on their part. (But of course, I'm not a "learner"! :)

Comment: ...by which I mean your comment (which I *have* upvoted) serves as a clear warning to learners exactly why they might wish to err on the side of "whiter than white" in this matter, even if they hear people like me apparently flouting the "rules" with gay abandon! Which makes it very useful, in our context here.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to simplify the issue as to why there must not be an inversion of questioning attached to a command or for that matter with any other sentence type expressing an assertion (statement), an emotion (exclamation) or a wish(optative). Sentences are meaningless if they become an odd assortment of  heterogeneous emotions put together. In a sentence the main clause (s) carries the spirit and other subordinate clauses add to that  spirit only. Your sentence may contain a bunch of statements, a plethora of commands or a fusillade of questions, but never all in one. That's why grammarians prescribe that barring your main sentence (s) others would be muted to statements or to phrases.

FumbleFingers has rightly mentioned that only No.(2) is correct where the question has been muted to a subordinate statement to elicit the  desired answer of the command/ request. There are two commands, alright! It would be meaningless if you add a question or  an optative or exclamatory sentence.